# MySql DB BackUp

Tags: mysql

How to take complete backup of mysql database using mysqldump command line utility?
I tried the following command :

```
mysqldump -u username -p password db1 > backup.sql
```

It gave error like You have an error in your SQL Syntax.Please Help..

Comment: Try this ..
**mysqldump -u username -ppassword db1 > backup.sql**

Comment: Did any solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backup: # `mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`

restore:# `mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

Ref: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Answer (score 2):

try like this- (remove space between -p and password)

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword db1 > backup.sql
```

For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: You dont need spaces after -u and -p. Also, some more options should added if a complete dump is to be made.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a `COMPLETE` backup, you need to add , `--all-databases`.

Like this

```
mysqldump -uUserName -ppassword --all-databases --routines > "fulldatabase.sql"
```

Note that you dont need spaces between -uUserName and -pPassword.

Also, if you are using a `PORT` in Mysql you must define the syntax like this

```
mysqldump -uUserName --password=password -P yourportnumber --all-databases 
--routines > "fulldatabase.sql"
```

This ensures all stored procedures are also dumped to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `mysqldump` to take entire backup as :

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb_backup.sql
```

and if you think dump file size is too large you can export in ZIP format as well:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | gzip -9 > [alldb_backup.sql.gz]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an entire DB, then:

```
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

If it's all DBs, then:

```
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] --all-databases > all_db_backup.sql
```

If it's specific tables within a DB, then:

```
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name table1 table2 > table_backup.sql
```

You can even go as far as auto-compressing the output using gzip (if your DB is very big):

```
$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name | gzip > db_backup.sql.gz
```

If you want to do this remotely and you have the access to the server in question, then the following would work (presuming the MySQL server is on port 3306):

```
$ mysqldump -P 3306 -h [ip_address] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```